# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo repeats

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

**I know this has been asked quite often but this one is quite different. the log file just posts the above exception several times without mentioning the cause. The log file is as given below**

---

```
01-31 09:53:10.305: E/AndroidRuntime(452): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 09:53:10.305: E/AndroidRuntime(452): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-31 09:53:10.305: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-31 09:53:10.305: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-31 09:53:10.305: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-31 09:53:10.305: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-31 09:53:10.305: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 09:53:10.305: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-31 09:53:10.305: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-31 09:53:10.305: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 09:53:10.305: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-31 09:53:10.305: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-31 09:53:10.305: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-31 09:53:10.305: E/AndroidRuntime(452):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 09:53:10.305: E/AndroidRuntime(452): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.iolcalci.Second}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.iolcalci/com.example.i
```

---

**The java file is as shown below**

```
package com.example.iolcalci;


import com.itab.graphics.TabBitmap;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Second extends ActivityGroup {
    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private static final String TAG_1 = "tab1";
    private static final String TAG_2 = "tab2";
    private static final String TAG_3 = "tab3";
    private static final String TAG_4 = "tab4";

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        setTabs();
    }
    private void setTabs() {
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(getLocalActivityManager());

        addTab("SRK/T", TAG_1, createTabDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_eye_unselected), new Intent(this, Second.class));
        addTab("SRK II", TAG_2, createTabDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_eye_unselected), new Intent(this, Srk2_x.class));
        addTab("BINKHORST", TAG_3, createTabDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_eye_unselected), new Intent(this, Binkhorst_x.class));
        addTab("HOLLADAY", TAG_4, createTabDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_eye_unselected), new Intent(this, Holladay_x.class));
    }
    private Drawable createTabDrawable(int resId) {
        Resources res = getResources();
        StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();

        final Options options = new Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        Bitmap unselected = TabBitmap.createUnselectedBitmap(res, icon);
        Bitmap selected = TabBitmap.createSelectedBitmap(res, icon);

        icon.recycle();

        states.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected }, new BitmapDrawable(res, selected));
        states.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled }, new BitmapDrawable(res, unselected));

        return states;
    }
    private View createTabIndicator(String label, Drawable drawable) {
        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.text_view_tab_title);
        txtTitle.setText(label);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) txtTitle.getLayoutParams();
        txtTitle.setLayoutParams(params);

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.image_view_tab_icon);
        imgIcon.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        return tabIndicator;
    }

    private void addTab(String label, String tag, Drawable drawable, Intent intent) {
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag);
        spec.setIndicator(createTabIndicator(label, drawable));
        spec.setContent(intent);
        mTabHost.addTab(spec);
    }


}
```

---

**XML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/Black" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height" >
            </TabWidget>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_srkt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_srk2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_holl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_bink"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

**Pls help. I couldn't figure out the problem**

Comment: did you add the Activity in your android_manifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is due to this line  `icon.recycle();` because `recycle()` method is free the native object associated with bitmap, and clear the reference to the pixel data. so try to use like this

```
 states.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected }, new BitmapDrawable(res, selected));
        states.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled }, new BitmapDrawable(res, unselected));
        icon.recycle();
```